# ERROR running force:source:pull: Cannot retrieve translation for object:X due to CustomObjectTranslation

Tags: salesforcedx, customobjecttranslation

When I run:

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

I am getting error:

> ERROR running force:source:pull:  Cannot retrieve translation for object:X

When I do a `sfdx force:source:status` I noticed there is a random `CustomObjectTranslation`

```
STATE       FULL NAME                   TYPE                     PROJECT PATH
──────────  ──────────────────────────  ───────────────────────  ────────────
Remote Add  X-en_US                     CustomObjectTranslation
```

I have no idea where this `CustomObjectTranslation` came from, and it's blocking my `pull`

Translation workbench is not enabled.

1. Why did it appear?
2. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I added an entry into the `.forceignore` for the metadata `CustomObjectTranslation` file in question, and then the `pull` worked.

It looks like it was due to me change the platform event name:

- [SFDX error on pull: Cannot retrieve translation for object:[platform event]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271988/sfdx-error-on-pull-cannot-retrieve-translation-for-objectplatform-event)